# Microsoft Moles not creating moles for several methods

Tags: moles

I am having a problem getting a couple of the static methods in my class to be *moled*, as well as getting the Diagnostics attribute in the .moles file to be recognized.

My environment:

- Visual Studio 2008
- Pex/Moles version 0.94.51023.0

The signature of the one method in particular that I *need* and can't get a moled reference to:

```
private static List<MaxBet> GetByPaytableDenom(int? paytableDenomId, int? paytableId, int? denomId, int? instanceId)
```

I have even tried changing it to `public static` or `private` (not static) and recompiled and can't get it to show up at all. It is one of 5 overloaded signatures of the same method. This one and one other aren't getting *moled*.

So I then tried turning on Diagnostics and Verbosity in my .mole file:

```
<Moles xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/moles/2010/" Diagnostic="true" Verbosity="Noisy">
```

And when I check the Output window and select the drop-down box to go to the Moles output, I am only getting this:

```
-- Moles vs build action build started
adding 2 assemblies
adding C:\WMS_2008\Development 4.X\BugFixes\Main 4.X\SourceNG\TestProjects\UnitTestProjects\BusinessLayerUnitTests\MolesAssemblies\WMS.NG.SSG.BusinessLayer.Moles.dll
adding C:\WMS_2008\Development 4.X\BugFixes\Main 4.X\SourceNG\TestProjects\UnitTestProjects\BusinessLayerUnitTests\MolesAssemblies\WMS.NG.SSG.DataLayer.Moles.dll
-- Moles update finished
```

What gives? I can't seem to figure this one out.

Cindy

Comment: What do the other signatures look like?

Comment: Could you please tell me where did you find info on those attributes you apply in .moles file? (I mean Diagnostic="true" Verbosity="Noisy"). Thanks

Comment: @superjos - I think I just opened the .moles file in VS2010 and used Intellisense to see the options.

Comment: thanks! BTW, you should mark your answer as _the_ answer, then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know now that the non-static methods show up in the AllInstances property of the moled class.

Thanks,
Cindy